# How to set header referrer in Angular6 + electron?

Tags: angular, electron, referrer

My project is build by Angular 6 + electron, when I request a url by angular httpclient, the server response 403. Then set the referrer, but not effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

There are few ways but this is the easy way.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
}

POST(){
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token': {{TOKEN}},
    });
    let options: any = {
       headers: headers
    }
    this.http.post(URL, param, options)
    .subscribe(data => {
         // Get res from API
    })
}
```

Comment: I set headers like this:
headers: {
        'Referer': 'https://xxx/api',
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
but in the electron devtools, the referer is  referer: file://  , no change

Comment: So what is the issue. I'm also using this right now. And it works fine

Comment: This way can set common params in header , but the param 'referer' is not ok

Comment: refere is key name ? which you want to pass in server ?